# What is the antenna connection on a European TV called?

Tags: television, cables, tv-antenna, coaxial-cable

I am looking for the name of the cable that goes from a 4-way TV splitter (the Power pass out input) to the back of my TV, as mine has broken and needs replacing.

This is to get my antenna and satellite connected.

[Here's an image](https://www.google.com/search?q=tv%20splitter%20diagram&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvrrSmuuvhAhWaVRUIHQAgDM4Q_AUIDigB&biw=1440&bih=727#imgrc=wzn--mMCJmd5pM) for reference. The cable from the splitter to TV 1 is the one I need the name of :)

I have bought a coaxial cable female to male but this does not fit.

Any help would be really really appreciated!

Comment: Your link comes up with a lot of different diagrams but most of them just seem to use standard “F” (screw-on) connectors. Can you please give us a photo of your actual unit?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. @DoxyLover is right: you almost certainly are talking about an [F connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_connector).

Comment: Thanks for responses. Is that F connector male to male? One has a screw top that goes into the power pass tv splitter though, so surely they are not the same ends?

Comment: If you follow the link that Daniel provided, you’ll see that the female has the external threads and the male has the center pin and internal threads. Typically, the cable has male connector on both ends. If you need to extend the cable, you can use a double-female barrel connector.

Comment: Again, if your splitter has a connector on it that is not the same as the others, you really need to provide a photo for use to give you a good answer.

Comment: Thanks. Here is [the splitter](https://imgur.com/a/hc8Lh1G) and the [antenna input for tv](https://imgur.com/UIpCWpu). Apologies, I am away from home, so could not provide better photos!

Comment: @DoxyLover I believe You have it backwards.  Male connectors have threads on the outside and female have threads on the inside. The male fits ( or screws ) INTO the female. This is true of pipe fittings as well.  In the case of coaxial cable the *female has the copper wire the fits into a hole in the male* but they are **designated by there treads not  the wire connection inside**, which seams counter intuitive or backwards.

Comment: @Alaskaman I’m following the Wikipedia page which clearly states the male has internal threads and the pin/wire sticking out the middle “The design allows for low-cost construction, where cables are terminated almost exclusively with **male** connectors. The coaxial cable center conductor forms the pin, and cable dielectric extends up to the mating face of the connector.” (Bolding mine)

Comment: @DoxyLover **I stand corrected !** i also found documentation that confirms you are correct.

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/T0pZHNQ) is an image of the splitter and input cable for my tv. I have 4 cables going into the splitter. The one shown in this is the input I need (because I need 2 of them, but I only have 1), but I do not know the name of it. It seems neither the [f connector male](https://amzn.to/2GClpul) or [fconnector female](https://amzn.to/2GGvEz0) will go into this. 

I do not want to wire my own cable or assemble anything together, so I am hoping that I can buy a cable that already has the ends/connectors on both sides already. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The photo you posted of  connection on the back of your TV is odd. I do not recognize the connector labeled antenna, the connector for the satellite is a coaxial F connection and that is what typical antenna connectors are in the USA. Do you have the manual for the TV, can you tell us the model number. Possible your tv came with an adapter for this

It is possibly a [Belling-Lee connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belling-Lee_connector)

Common in Europe and the Australia.

if you are handy you can put a Belling-Lee connector on a coaxial cable. [How to wire a Belling-Lee connector](http://www.megalithia.com/elect/bellinglee/)

I found [this](https://www.220stores.com/store/p/859-Male-PAL-Belling-Lee-amp-Female-NTSC-F-RF-Coaxial-Connector.html) adapter to convert an f connector to a belling-lee.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thanks for for your response. The tv I have is a [Philips 43PUS6753](www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07CD2DJLY/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_o3EWCbHC29KVD)

Comment: i believe it is the Belling-Lee -  https://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/43PUS6753_12/6700-series-ultra-slim-4k-uhd-led-smart-tv-with-ambilight-3-sided/overview

Comment: **European antenna connection name: Belling-Lee connector.** I can't remember if an RCA plug will fit or not. They're different by .021ths of an inch...

Comment: RCAs will **not** fit Belling-Lees and vice versa.

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/T0pZHNQ) is an image of the splitter and input cable for my tv. I have 4 cables going into the splitter. The one shown in this is the input I need (because I need 2 of them, but I only have 1), but I do not know the name of it. It seems neither the f connector male or fconnector female will go into the splitter without making my own connected wire. I do not want to wire my own cable or assemble anything together, so I am hoping that I can buy a cable that already has the ends/connectors on both sides already?

Comment: @MariaC - Based on the image in your latest comment - you need an F connector. You can buy a cable with these on it [(example](https://www.screwfix.com/p/satellite-lead-f-plug-to-f-plug-1m/61186?kpid=61186&ds_kid=92700024374094144&ds_rl=1241687&ds_rl=1245250&ds_rl=1249401&ds_rl=1248154&ds_rl=1245250&ds_rl=1247848&gclid=EAIaIQobChMItJaCoe_t4QIVECjTCh3EYQCKEAQYBCABEgLd0_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds))

Comment: Maria, i think you can use a coaxial cable with f connectors. One end to the splitter and on the other end,  ( *with the adapter i listed above* ), to connect to the belling-lee port on you tv.

Comment: Thank you all. I have found the right cable [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/KabelDirekt-Cable-F-type-connector-Black-Grey/dp/B073RGNFC3/ref=asc_df_B073RGNFC3/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=218715807545&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12672155307557325943&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9041110&hvtargid=pla-421347534229&psc=1). It was indeed f connector end with female SAT/TV cable. :)